# How to Access a Textbox Value from Page to UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having an aspx page(example.aspx) with text box control(txtid) and on the same page i am creating a user control(access.ascx) with an image button(click.png). i have to retrieve the text box(txtid) into the user control. how can i retrieve the value of text box control(txtid) in to the usercontrol page(access.ascx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like:

```
TextBox txt= (TextBox)this.Parent.FindControl("txtid");
```

that would go in your usercontrol.  this.Parent should get you a reference to the example.aspx page.

Answer (score 2):

In your user control, you can add a property like:

```
public property Text
{
  ..
}
```

And then the page can assign the value from the page's textbox to this property, which the user control can then use.  You could also use a `SetText(string text)` method too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)this.Parent.FindControl("txtid")
```

Comment: same answer already given by @Paritosh

Comment: @Rahul kisi ke answer same nahi ho sakte kya..?

Comment: In same question two same answer with same control name like "txtid",,very funny..

Comment: read question first..I am having an aspx page(example.aspx) with text box control(txtid)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your user control:

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)this.FindSiblingControl("txtid");
```

Supporting method:

```
public static class StaticClassToHandleExtensions
{
    public static Control FindSiblingControl(this Control control, string id)
    {
        Control parent = control.Parent;
        while (parent.GetType() != typeof(ContentPlaceHolder) && parent.GetType() != typeof(Page))
            parent = parent.Parent;

        return parent.FindControl(id);
    }
}
```

The first level `Parent` may not be on the same level as your control so you'll need to keep going higher up. This example with stop on `ContentPlaceHolder` which will be the top level for a page is it has a master page of `Page` which will be the top level for a page without a master page. The `FindControl` method will search its entire tree of controls, meaning it will search multiple level deep so this is the safest and easiest solution.

Comment: Or your ascx may contain a public property Page with name lets say MyParentPage, where you can hold the actual Page reference.